# Two different Arrays are referencing each other in C

Tags: c++, arrays, c, char, c-strings

I am very new to C / C++ and I am learning the basics. I want to write a program that prints the number of vowels as `vowCount` in a person's name that is an input. I have two `char` arrays, `name[20]` to hold the `string` input from the user and `vowels[]` to hold vowels.

I want `vowCount` to increase by 1 if two `char`s match between the arrays. If I input `name` as "John", the nested `for-loop`, `vowels[i]` prints `a,e,i,o,u,J,o,h,n`. What is my mistake here and I don't understand why `vowels[i]` also prints elements from `name[20]`? And `vowCount` is always the same as the size of `name[]`, including the `null` pointer at the end of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char name[20];
    char vowels[] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
    int vowCount = 0;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%19s",name);
    for(uint16_t counter = 0; name[counter]!= '\0' ;counter++ ){
        char test = name[counter];

        printf("CHECKING: %c \n", test);
        for(uint8_t i =0; vowels[i] != '\0'; i++){
            printf("COMPARING WITH VOWEL: %c\n", vowels[i]);
            if(test == vowels[i]){
                vowCount++;
            }

        }
    }

    printf("\n%i", vowCount);

}
```

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you applied. In short, there is no such thing as "C / C++".

Comment: The way you initialized it, you didn't put a null terminator in vowels[], but your code relies on one being present. Use either `char vowels[] = {'a','e','i','o','u','\0'};` or `char vowels[] = "aeiou"};` or limit your iteration by the size of the array.

Comment: `namespaces` in C, @TheDreamsWind?

Comment: You are treating array `vowels` as if it contained a C string, but it does not, because C strings are terminated by a null character, and `vowels` does not contain one.

Comment: Since you have a `namespace` statement, this must be C++, not C. Why are you using C-style strings instead of `std::string`?

Comment: What you are experiencing is called a buffer overrun. You are erroneously accessing past the end of the buffer you are trying to use.

Comment: @AviBerger I have made the changes and they work perfectly! Thank you so much! Also may I ask, in my case that I forgot to add ```\0``` at the end of ```vowels[]```, it will then just point to another existing array that has ```\0```? Is this the ```string``` behaviour in C?

Comment: @Barmar Oh I see. Sorry I didn't know that ```namespace``` belongs to C++, it is just my second day learning C and C++, I am very new. But thank you for the information!

Comment: Are you really learning C and C++ at the same time? I suggest you pick one and master that.

Comment: Officially it is undefined behavior. In practice it is likely that it will run through whatever follows it in memory (which is not necessarily a char array, or even initialized memory) until it happens to hit a byte with a value of '\0' or tries to access an address your program doesn't have access to. This last possibility is likely to crash your program with a "seg fault".

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately it is a course from my university titled "Software Development with C and C++"... I guess I have to do both at the same time... and we have had no experience in both languages at all in previous semesters :(

Comment: @AviBerger That is very interesting and informative. I understand the error now. Thank you!

Comment: @zachlee22 A course trying to teach you C *and* C++, at the same time even, is *wasting your time*. Most of the things you learn to do in C are *terrible* practice in C++. Seriously. Don't do this to yourself -- getting stuck in the middle between those two languages is a terrible place to be, and will likely result in yourself being frustrated by both. C++ is best learned "top down", i.e. without learning C first (and then having to unlearn all the bad parts).

Comment: @DevSolar Thank you for the information and advice, I will keep that in mind. For now I will try to get through (and hopefully pass) this course and then eventually continue to explore these two languages in the proper way.

Comment: @zachlee22 ;-) I recommend [Kate Gregory: Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk), a talk from CppCon 2015. Even if you won't understand much of the syntactic details, you might get an idea of what I was referring to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This array

```
char vowels[] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
```

does not contain a string: a sequence of characters terminated by the zero character `'\0'`.

As a result this for loop

```
for(uint8_t i =0; vowels[i] != '\0'; i++){
```

invokes undefined behavior because neither element of the array `vowels` is equal to `'\0'`.

Instead you could declare the array either like

```
char vowels[] = {'a','e','i','o','u', '\0' };
```

or you could use a string literal to initialize the array

```
char vowels[] = { "aeiou" };
```

that is the same as

```
char vowels[] = "aeiou";
```

Pay attention to that in C there are no namespaces. If you want to write a C program then remove this line

```
using namespace std;
```

Also neither declaration from the header `<string.h>` is used in your program.

A C program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char name[20];
    const char vowels[] = "aeiou";
    size_t vowCount = 0;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf( "%19s", name );

    for ( size_t i = 0; name[i]!= '\0' ; i++ )
    {
        unsigned char c = name[i];

        printf("CHECKING: %c \n", c );

        if ( strchr( vowels, tolower( c ) ) != NULL )
        {
            vowCount++;
        }
    }

    printf( "\n%zu\n", vowCount );
}
```

Comment: `strchr( tolower( c ) )`? Please edit.